# How do I remove empty space between an enclosed header and a box border?

Tags: html, css

**HTML**

```
<ASIDE><H2>Sample H2</H2>
Sample content.
</ASIDE>
```

**CSS**

```
ASIDE {border: darkkhaki solid medium;}
ASIDE H2 {background-color: darkkhaki;}
```

I want this to display as a box with the heading in a thick bar at the very top of the box that matches the color of the box's border, but what I get instead is a gap of whitespace between the H2 and the top border of the box. I have checked this in multiple browsers, and it is the same. So, this is standard behavior, not the quirk of a particular browser. What can I do to remove the gap of whitespace that appears between the H2 and the top border?

Here is a [jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/1qpnwupx/2/).

Answer (score 4):

Add `margin-top: 0;` to your `ASIDE H2` div to remove the gap.

**CSS**

```
ASIDE H2 {
  background-color: darkkhaki;
  margin-top: 0;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/1qpnwupx/3/)

Comment: ahh just ahead of me haha

Comment: Haha, sorry bud ;D

Answer (score 3):

This seems to be a margin issue.

The fix is very simple.  Just add a `margin-top: 0` to your `ASIDE H2` in your CSS.

**HTML:**

```
<ASIDE><H2>Sample H2</H2>
Sample content.
</ASIDE>
```

**CSS:**

```
ASIDE {border: darkkhaki solid medium;}
ASIDE H2 {background-color: darkkhaki; margin-top: 0;}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k2h1o56f/)